# jquery error TypeError: Value not an object. with .split(',')

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am getting a strange error

```
Error: TypeError: Value not an object.
Source File: /Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js
Line: 4
```

while i am trying to do a .split() with javascript.

Following is the snippet :

```
$("#item_qty_1").on("keydown", function (event) {

if (event.which == 13) {

    var weight_code = $("#weight_code").val();
    var qty = Number($(this).val());

    if((weight_code == "2" || weight_code == "3") && qty <= 50)
    {

        var qty_sub_val = document.getElementById('item_qty_sub').value;
        var qty_sub = "";

        console.log(typeof qty_sub_val);
        if(qty_sub_val != "" && qty_sub_val !== null)
        {
            qty_sub = qty_sub_val.split(',');
        }

        $("#test").html(qty_sub);

        for(var i=1; i<=50; i++)
        {
            if(i>qty)
            {
                $("#qty_" + i).attr("tabindex","-1").attr("readonly","readonly").removeAttr("last").css("background","#e6e6e6");
            }
            else
            {
                if(qty_sub_val != "")
                {
                    $("#qty_" + i).attr("tabindex",i).removeAttr("readonly").removeAttr("last").css("background","white").val(qty_sub[i-1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#qty_" + i).attr("tabindex",i).removeAttr("readonly").removeAttr("last").css("background","white");
                }
            }
        }
        $("#qty_" + qty).attr("last","0");
        $("#unit1_list").modal();   
    }

    event.preventDefault(); 
    return false;
}

});
```

it is giving error only when qty_sub_val != ""; i.e. when .split(',') is called.

Comment: What are you getting as the value of `qty_sub_val` ? Did you try alerting it ?

Comment: Why are you adding `$("#item_qty_sub").val() + "";` double quotes at last?

Comment: ``$("#item_qty_sub").val() + ""; better be: `$("#item_qty_sub").val() || "";`

Comment: working here - with 1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: is `#item_qty_sub` a `<select>` element by any chance? if so: jQ returns `null` when nothing was selected. Also `<select multiple>` returns an array, not a string. Best check the return value of `$.val()`, then. And as always: you haven't forgotten about `$(document).ready(function(){/*code here*/});` have you?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem : no its a text box.

Comment: @NitinKabra: try `console.log(typeof qty_sub_val)`, and perhaps set up [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: its string.

Comment: @NitinKabra: There's got to be something you're not telling us, or something you're missing. You've added `console.log(typeof qty_sub_val)` just above the `split` call? Does `qty_sub_val.length` cause problems, too? or `.indexOf()`? Please, set up a fiddle, or show the value of `qty_sub_val`

Answer (score 0):

Please check what `$("#item_qty_sub")` returns. I think it is not returning the right value.

Comment: it is returning the right value. i tried printing the value in div, which is working fine.

Comment: Okay, try storing that value in a variable and do the split. For example: var str = "value of  $("#item_qty_sub")" and then do a split str.spli(',').

Comment: @user1794058: That's what he's doing: `var qty_sub_val = $('#item_qty_sub');`... and that's not working for some bizarre reason...

Comment: No, He is doing an split directly on whatever $('#item_qty_sub') returns, I want him to increase one line of code.

Comment: @user1794058: He's calling `split` on wherever `.val` returns when called on the return value of `$('#item_qty_sub')`, check the question: `var qty_sub_val = $("#item_qty_sub").val();`<-- `.val()` is there